# Possible 4 digit numbers whose individual digit sum is equal to n

Tags: c

I was making this little program using loops in C where I have to find the total number of **possible 4 digits** whose **individual digit sum** will be **equal to n** (user input).

But it's not working for some reason.
Edit: Sorry for the improper explanation, when I executed the program it gave me long random numbers in arr1,arr2,arr3

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int num,i,j,k,l,n,n1,n2,n3,pos=0;
    int arr0[100],arr1[100],arr2[100],arr3[100];
    printf("enter the number(must be an Integer!) of which you want to find out possibilities of 4 division\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);

    n=num-3;
    n1=n-2;
    n2=n1-1;

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        n1=num-i;
        for(j=1;i<=n1;j++)
        {
            n2=n1-j;
            for(k=1;i<=n2;k++)
            {
                n3=n2-k;
                for(l=1;i<=n3;l++)
                {
                    arr0[pos]=i;
                    arr1[pos]=j;
                    arr2[pos]=k;
                    arr3[pos]=l;
                    pos++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<pos;i++)
    {
        printf("%d%d%d%d\n",arr0[pos],arr1[pos],arr2[pos],arr3[pos]);
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: `But its not working for some reason` Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: And please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Wrong algorithm.  Say `num==1`, the answer should be 4: (1000, 100, 10, 1)

Comment: hint: digit can take only values `[0-9]`, not `n` as in your loops

Comment: Small point: `pos++;` should be moved a few lines down from the start to the end of that code block.

Comment: `n3=n2-k;
                for(l=1;i<=n3;l++)` iterates, when only one or zero solutions may be valid.  Perhaps `n3=n2-k; l = n3; if (l >= 0 && l <= 9)`?

Comment: Carefully review `pos` in `arr0[pos]` in `for(i=1;i<pos;i++)
    {
        printf("%d%d%d%d\n",arr0[pos],arr1[pos],arr2[pos],arr3[pos]);
    }`

Comment: thanks guys, ill check these up!

Comment: Nvm, I changed the whole program. I also took the help of the hint @IIya Bursov

Answer (score 0):

A few bugs ...

You are indexing some of your arrays by `pos` which doesn't help too much.

I've run your code and it seems to loop for a long time. As others have mentioned, you're not restricting your digit entries to `0-9`. Also, some of your arrays get wild/large values.

You can use nested loops to do this. That is, iterate over the digit combinations but I think you'd only need a single 4 element array. That is, generate the digit string and test it and add to a sum if the digit string is valid (i.e. sum of digits matches `num`).

---

You *can* use 4 nested loops to do this,
but what if the number of digits was arbitrary (and could be specified at runtime)?

Using a variable length array of ndigits and incrementing them with carry out is an alternative to the nested arrays

I couldn't make sense of your algorithm, so I created a version from scratch. It is simpler than what I think your logic was trying to achieve.

Instead of asking the user for a `num` value, it tests all possible `num` values.

Perhaps this will give you some ideas that can help you understand what is happening with your own version. In particular, note how the carry/rollover is handled when a digit gets to 10.

Anyway, here is what I came up with. It tests all `num` values in the range `0-9999` and takes 0.8 seconds in total.

Once a given `num` fails (i.e. has no matching digit combinations), we can stop early because no digit combination will ever match again. With the early escape option `-f`, the program takes 8ms.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int opt_f;                              // 1=test all numbers
int opt_r;                              // 1=print lowest to highest
int opt_z;                              // 1=exclude anything with leading 0
int opt_v;                              // 1=output matching numbers
int opt_N;                              // num value to use
int opt_W;                              // digit width

int
test(int num,const int *digits)
{
    int sum = 0;
    int digidx;
    int match;

    for (digidx = 0;  digidx < opt_W;  ++digidx)
        sum += digits[digidx];

    match = (sum == num);

    // decide which digit is most significant
    if (opt_r)
        digidx = opt_W - 1;
    else
        digidx = 0;

    // ensure number has no leading zeroes
    if (opt_z) {
        if (! digits[digidx])
            match = 0;
    }

    return match;
}

int
calc(int num)
{
    int digits[opt_W];
    int showflg = 1;
    int carry;
    int tot = 0;

    // reset digit string to all zeroes
    for (int digidx = 0;  digidx < opt_W;  ++digidx)
        digits[digidx] = 0;

    while (1) {
        // test number and print if it matches
        if (test(num,digits)) {
            if (tot == 0) {
                printf("\n");
                printf("NUM: %d\n",num);
            }

            tot += 1;

            // output the number
            if (opt_v) {
                printf("  ");
                if (! opt_r) {
                    for (int digidx = 0;  digidx < opt_W;  ++digidx)
                        printf("%d",digits[digidx]);
                }
                else {
                    for (int digidx = opt_W - 1;  digidx >= 0;  --digidx)
                        printf("%d",digits[digidx]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
        }

        // increment to next digit string
        carry = 0;
        for (int digidx = 0;  digidx < opt_W;  ++digidx) {
            // increment the current digit
            digits[digidx] += 1;

            // see if we get a carry out on this digit -- bug out if not
            carry = (digits[digidx] > 9);
            if (! carry)
                break;

            // reset this digit to zero
            digits[digidx] = 0;
        }

        // carry out from most significant digit means stop
        if (carry)
            break;
    }

    if (tot)
        printf("TOT: %d\n",tot);

    return tot;
}

int
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    char *cp;

    opt_f = 1;
    opt_r = 1;
    opt_z = 1;
    opt_v = 0;
    opt_W = 4;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    for (;  argc > 0;  --argc, ++argv) {
        cp = *argv;
        if (*cp != '-')
            break;

        switch (cp[1]) {
        case 'f':  // flip test all numbers
            opt_f = ! opt_f;
            break;

        case 'r':  // flip low-to-high
            opt_r = ! opt_r;
            break;

        case 'v':  // flip verbosity
            opt_v = ! opt_v;
            break;

        case 'z':  // flip skip on leading zeroes
            opt_z = ! opt_z;
            break;

        case 'N':  // num value to use
            opt_N = atoi(cp + 2);
            break;

        case 'W':  // set digit width
            opt_W = atoi(cp + 2);
            break;
        }
    }

    // get upper limit of number to test
    int lim = 1;
    for (int num = 1;  num <= opt_W;  ++num)
        lim *= 10;

    printf("WID: %d (%d)\n",opt_W,lim);

    // test all numbers within the range
    int num;
    if (opt_z && (! opt_f))
        num = 1;
    else
        num = 0;
    if (opt_N) {
        num = opt_N;
        lim = num + 1;
    }
    for (;  num < lim;  ++num) {
        if (calc(num))
            continue;
        if (! opt_f)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the program output:

```
WID: 4 (10000)

NUM: 1
TOT: 1

NUM: 2
TOT: 4

NUM: 3
TOT: 10

NUM: 4
TOT: 20

NUM: 5
TOT: 35

NUM: 6
TOT: 56

NUM: 7
TOT: 84

NUM: 8
TOT: 120

NUM: 9
TOT: 165

NUM: 10
TOT: 219

NUM: 11
TOT: 279

NUM: 12
TOT: 342

NUM: 13
TOT: 405

NUM: 14
TOT: 465

NUM: 15
TOT: 519

NUM: 16
TOT: 564

NUM: 17
TOT: 597

NUM: 18
TOT: 615

NUM: 19
TOT: 615

NUM: 20
TOT: 597

NUM: 21
TOT: 564

NUM: 22
TOT: 519

NUM: 23
TOT: 465

NUM: 24
TOT: 405

NUM: 25
TOT: 342

NUM: 26
TOT: 279

NUM: 27
TOT: 219

NUM: 28
TOT: 165

NUM: 29
TOT: 120

NUM: 30
TOT: 84

NUM: 31
TOT: 56

NUM: 32
TOT: 35

NUM: 33
TOT: 20

NUM: 34
TOT: 10

NUM: 35
TOT: 4

NUM: 36
TOT: 1
```

Answer (score -1):

well I wanted to find out possible 4 digits whose individual sum would be equal to a certain assigned number
eg: 5 =1112 
here is my updated code, but now I want to make sure there are no repetitions :/

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
int num,m,i,j,k,l,n,n1,n2,n3,pos=0;
int a0[100],a1[100],a2[100],a3[100];
printf("enter the number(must be an Integer!) of which you want to find out possibilities of 4 division\n");
scanf("%d",&num);

while(num<4)
{
    printf("**ERROR** please enter a valid number(Integer) that can be divided into 4 division\n");
    scanf("%d",&num);
}

for(i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    for(j=1;j<=9;j++)
    {
        for(k=1;k<=9;k++)
        {
            for(l=1;l<=9;l++)
            {
                if((i+j+k+l)==num)
                {
                a0[pos]=i;
                a1[pos]=j;
                a2[pos]=k;
                a3[pos]=l;
                pos+=1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

for(m=0;m<pos;m++)
{
    printf("%d%d%d%d\n",a0[m],a1[m],a2[m],a3[m]);
}

return(0);
}
```